# Width & Height of MediaQuery.of(context).size are zero

Tags: flutter, dart

is there anyone facing the same issue in flutter 3.10.1, Dart 3.0.1?
The

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

and

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

are always 0.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

and

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

had worked with no issue in previous Flutter 2.19, but i get this issue after upgrade.

Comment: post the code with where you call it

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height=MediaQuery.of(context).height;

Comment: The call in above attached block worked in previous flutter.

Comment: I have 3.10 and it works just fine, post the minimal not working code, the code that could be run to reproduce the issue

Comment: Generally, any scaling that is driven by device width is wrong. TL;DR: use LayoutBuilder (not MediaQuery) to determine breakpoints only (side nav vs bottom nav, two columns vs three). Then use Flex widgets (Row, Column, Expanded, Spacer, etc) to lay out your text. Do not change the font size.

The way to remember this is to think back to the last time you made a web page or a desktop app wider. Did the characters get bigger? No? :) Then stop making your apps "scale" font sizes. Use width to re-layout, not re-size.

Comment: @pskink I faced simular issues after updating Flutter from 3.7.12 to 3.10.5, but in widget test: previously MediaQuery.of(context).size.width returned 800 but now it returns 0

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue - MediaQuery.of(context).size.width return zero and it works in Flutter 3.7.12 but stop works in 3.10.5.
In my case it happens cause one of my widgets was wrapped with MediaQuery:

```
  return MediaQuery(
    data: const MediaQueryData(),
    child: MaterialApp(home: home),
  );
```

I just removed this MediaQuery and it works

Answer (score 0):

I am calling it like

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    dev.log('Width:  ${screenSize.width}');
    dev.log('Heigth:  ${screenSize.height}');
....}
```

And this is working flawless for me! I have always the newest stable update.

I also tried to call it in a really small Container, also then I still get the full size of the screen.

- since you updated, there are some other parts not working fine, so you size measurement doesnt fire correctly
- You have to clean your project like: 1) flutter clean, 2) flutter pub get 3) close and reopen your editor. (If you want repeat 1 and 2).
- You calling it wrong?

(Less Likely):

- you are using a real device and it is blocking it some how?
- your emulator is blocking it or its "broken"?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I just created a new simple flutter, and it works very well. I'll be looking into cleaning my project.

Answer (score 0):

I use Getx and Sizer wrapping over `MaterialApp ()`. Yes that happens with me too. Not only that, your `runApp()` and sometimes even `void main()` also gets run multiple times. I think that problem is from flutter side. But if in your case only `runApp()` gets run multiple times then, currently I solved it by ...

```
if(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 0) return MaterialApp();
return const SizedBox();
```

you need to use builder or StatelessWidget for context. If you find any better solution from project setting, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been noticing that sometimes I'll 0-size media queries at startup, on the first build, and it is quickly followed by a build with a media query with the right size. I suspect it's a timing issue, as I only see it intermittently. I see it more often on release builds. It's as if the app tree gets built before the context is ready, and then it builds again when ready.

It was causing issues for me because I was caching the size for use in some code that doesn't have access to the context. Conditionally building the app only when the size is greater than 0 looks like a reasonable fix for me.